# Discrepancy with absolute value in evaluating a triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate

$$\iiint z^2 \,dx\,dy\,dz $$

over the region common to the sphere
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$$
and the cylinder
$$x^2 + y^2 = ax.$$

**Approach**:

working in cylindrical co-ordinates, the integral should simply boil down to:-
$$\int_{-\pi / 2}^{\pi / 2} \int_0^{a\cos \phi} \int_{-\sqrt{a^2-s^2}}^{\sqrt{a^2-s^2}} z^2 \,dz\,d\phi$$

Which boils down to evaluating :

$$ \frac 2 3 \int_{-\pi / 2}^{\pi / 2}d\phi\int_0^{a\cos \phi} (a^2-s^2)^{3/2}s\,ds $$

Let $(a^2-s^2)=u^2$. Then, we get

$$ \frac 2 3 \int_{-\pi / 2}^{\pi / 2}\,d\phi \int_{a\left|\sin\phi\right|}^a u^4\,du \tag{E01} $$

Notice the $|\cdot|$ in the lower limit. (this was done as a result of $\sqrt{x^2}= |x|$ while changing the limits).  This will be the root cause of the trouble that follows:-

$$\frac{2a^5}{15} \int_{-\pi / 2}^{\pi / 2} (1-\left| \sin^5\phi \right|)\,d\phi = \frac{2a^5}{15} ( \pi - I)$$

Now, had the $| \cdot |$ **not** been present in $E01$, then $I$
would be $0$, since $\sin^5\phi$ is odd. So the answer would be $2\pi/15$.

But, the $|\cdot|$ means that $I$ would be something positive, which would mean the answer is something **less** than $2\pi/15$.

However, the given answer is: $2\pi/15$. Which made me question the existence of the $|\cdot|$.

Seems to be rather trivial that the $|\cdot|$ should be there.....The second scope for an error could be in determining the limits of the integral...But that seems fine too.

Where have I gone wrong then? Or do I just accept that the book "forgot" the $|\cdot|$ and I am indeed right?

Comment: oops. Edited. Made another typo (4 instead of 2).

Comment: @MathLover $ u^2= (a^2-s^2)$. for $s= acos\phi$, $u^2= a^2sin^2\phi$. So, $u= a|sin\phi|$. Note that $\sqrt{x^2}= |x|$ as I have mentioned.

Comment: @Lizzi sigh, another typo. Edited.

Comment: Why don't you substitute with $u=(a^2-s^2)$, Then $ds = -\frac{1}{2s} du$ That seems more practicable to me.

Comment: @Lizzi you will still eventually get the $| | $ .

Comment: @MathLover I dont understand what you are doing. It seems that you are not accepting the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}= |x| $

Comment: @satan29 yes that was my mistake.

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. $\displaystyle \int_0^{a\cos\phi}$ rather than $\displaystyle \int_0^{a cos\phi}$ and other things.

Comment: @Lizzi : Since you post questions on integration, can you write things like $\int\int\int zs \,ds \,dz \,d\phi$ instead of $\int\int\int zs ds dz d\phi\text{?} \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right, the absolute values should be there. Anyone who doubts is invited to write the integral as two times the integral over the upper half of the region (since the problem is symmetric with respect to $z$), so that you get $2 \int_0^{\pi/2}$ instead of $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$. Then there are no absolute values involved, and without question you do get a contribution from that $\sin^5 \phi$ term.

For what it's worth, Mathematica agrees: `Integrate[z^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x^2 + y^2 <= x, {x, y, z}]]`
returns
$$
\frac{2}{225}(-16+15\pi)
,
$$
or in other words
$$
\frac{2\pi}{15} - \frac{32}{225}
.
$$
(That's with $a=1$, obviously. To get the result for any $a>0$, just multiply by $a^5$, for dimensional reasons.)